# Better way to access siblings

Tags: jquery

I have 3 siblings:

```
 ----------------------
 | div1 | div2 | div3 |
 ----------------------
```

I need to find the siblings(specifically their '#id') of the current div I am interacting with. Right now I have a couple `if else` statements however I think there is a more efficient way to do this.

I originally had:

```
var siblingOne = $(div).siblings([0]).attr('id'); 
var siblingTwo = $(div).siblings([1]).attr('id');
```

However it would always select the same sibling for `siblingOne` and `siblingTwo` no matter the `siblings([index])`.

So I ended up using this method- which worked but is a little extra work.

```
function foo(div){
    if(div == "#div1"){
        var siblingOne = $(div).next().attr('id');
        var siblingTwo = $(div).next().next().attr('id');
    }
    else if(div == "#div2"){
        var siblingOne = $(div).prev().attr('id');
        var siblingTwo = $(div).next().attr('id');
    }
    else{
        var siblingOne = $(div).prev().attr('id');
        var siblingTwo = $(div).prev().prev().attr('id');
    }
}
```

Later on I apply: `('#'+siblingOne)` and `('#'+siblingOne)` so that I can access the id if that makes sense.

Thanks. Any suggestions?

Comment: `.siblings([0])`, what is that???

Comment: I always thought the siblings were indexed... perhaps that was my original problem.

Comment: You'd have better to explain what you are looking for instead. I don't really see why you need IDs here anyway. And to use siblings index: `.siblings().eq(0)` which return already a jq object

Comment: You could do `.siblings()[0]`, but not `.siblings([0])`. The parameter is a selector, and passing an array with a single index isn't a valid selector.

Comment: @A.Wolff I use the name of the IDs that I select to access other divs. For example: `$(siblingOne+'Page').hide();` If it wasn't for that I would just pass the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
var $siblings = $(currentDiv).siblings();

var sibling1Id = $siblings[0].id;
var sibling2Id = $siblings[1].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe call them by their parent?

```
$("#container").children().each(function(){
    $(this).dosomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = $(div).siblings().map(function(i,o){ return $(o).attr('id'); })
```

This will return an array of ids.
Then you can access the first id with `ids[0]` and the second one with `ids[1]`